# how to get property from MSI handler during installation, and pass it to uninstall function

Tags: properties, get, installshield

In basic MSI project, I add a property "id" in Installation Designer table,set its default value is 50, when I install the service, I set a new value 48 to this property, and use MsiGetProperty(hMSI, "id", ID, nvSize) to get new value, it works fine. but when I unintall the service, use MsiGetProperty(hMSI, "id", ID, nvSize) once more, I only get the default value 50 instead of new value 48.Why?

How can i get the new value during uninstallation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because during installation you modify this property only for this instance of installation. It means, when you launch uninstallation - property will have default (initial) value. 
The one way to solve this issue - create Registry entry with actual value of **id** (`HKLM\Software\MySoftware\id=48` for example) and during uninstallation just read it with help of *SystemSearch* to property **id**.

Comment: thanks for your reply. This is a solution. I adopt another workaround.

Comment: I store the id in install path, for example, "c:\\048", during uninstallation, I get property "INSTALLDIR", get this value, and extract the id value.